# showModalDialog - IE11 ignores dialogHeight and dialogWidth

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-11, showmodaldialog

I am experiencing a problem whith `showModalDialog` on `IE11`. The dialog window works fine, but **ignores the width and height** parameters. The dialog opens in a very small window and the user needs to resize it.

I know that this function is deprecated in Chrome and I know other options like jQuery-UI dialog, but I want to know if it is possible to fix this problem for IE11 using `showModalDialog`.

js code:

```
var url = "/xxWar/xxModal.jsp?title=xx&frameUrl=/xxWar/xxServlet%3Faction%3Dxx";
var value = showModalDialog(url, init, "dialogWidth:" + width + "px;dialogHeight:" + height + "px;resizable:yes;status:no;scroll:yes;help:no");
```

and the xxModal.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title><%=request.getParameter("title")%></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="0,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame src="" name="header">
        <frame src="<%=request.getParameter("frameUrl")%>" name="main" id="main">
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        <body>
        </body>
    </noframes>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem adding this line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">` inside de modal.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title><%=request.getParameter("title")%></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="0,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame src="" name="header">
        <frame src="<%=request.getParameter("frameUrl")%>" name="main" id="main">
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        <body>
        </body>
    </noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Comment: Hello, I used this solution by adding it to the HTML file of the modal pop-up. My browser is IE11 and it worked. Is there a reason why the content value has to be "IE=7" specifically?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to go back as far as IE7, setting `content="IE=9"` works too - that's what we use & we set height & width according to our needs ;)